# What refer/mean "Remote Server Authentication" at Apache mod_ssl doc?

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, certificate-authority, mod-ssl

The part of the doc in that such term is used is [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#page-header). Can anybody give some context or explain me what mean Remote Server Authentication there? I know that Apache server can authenticate clients but not a "Sever"?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after continue reading I realize that "Remote Server Authentication" is in the context of SSL proxy, where Apache play the role of client of whatever server it is proxy-ing.